# Dealing with changing properties of a "ProblemFact" in a shift planning scenario?

Tags: optaplanner

I am using OptaPlanner to calculate shifts (meaning start-time, end-time and necessary qualifications) from a set of tasks that need to be handled on a day.

I use a drools score director and have setup a number of rules to assign the tasks to shifts while keeping constraints like:

- never assign overlapping tasks to the same shift
- never have two tasks assigned to the same shift when this would result in violating the maximum shift length
- never have two tasks on the same shift when there is no possible set of qualifcations matching the necessary qualifications of both tasks
  etc.

So far I get pretty decent results.
However there is one optimization left. It should be possible to have shifts of different lengths (e. 8 hour, 6 hour and 4 hour shifts) and there is a threshold at which a shift is considered productive (e.g. if 60% of the time are covered by the tasks). So it would be better to have more, shorter but productive shifts than long unproductive ones.

I have difficulties to define something like that as a rule. The problem is in my opinion that this is kind of a property of the shift. The shift however is my planning fact and therefore cannot change it's state during the calculation.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
  Hendrik

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that `Task` and `Shift` are problem facts, and `TaskAssignment` is a planning entity which is defined by a `task` and has a planning variable `shift`.

```
when
  $s: Shift($t : treshold)
  $totalTime : Number(intValue < $t) from accumulate (TaskAssignment(shift == $s, $t : time) sum($t))
then
  add($t - $totalTime)
end
```